# How to make sftp output a working sftp prompt after the connection from CLI arguments is created?

Tags: scripting, ftp, sftp, arguments, output

I get a program that stays in input state, the user can type characters but they are useless.

The following are the command and the output. After this, the terminal prints the keys pressed.

```
~  sftp -vvv sftp://usr@url:21
OpenSSH_8.5p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1j  16 Feb 2021
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts' -> '/home/silviub/.ssh/known_hosts'
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts2' -> '/home/silviub/.ssh/known_hosts2'
debug2: resolving "[url]" port 21
debug3: ssh_connect_direct: entering
debug1: Connecting to [url] [my-ip-here] port 21.
debug3: set_sock_tos: set socket 3 IP_TOS 0x48
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/silviub/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /home/silviub/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/silviub/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/silviub/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/silviub/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/silviub/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/silviub/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /home/silviub/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/silviub/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/silviub/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/silviub/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /home/silviub/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/silviub/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /home/silviub/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.5
debug1: kex_exchange_identification: banner line 0: 220---------- Welcome to Pure-FTPd [privsep] [TLS] ----------
debug1: kex_exchange_identification: banner line 1: 220-You are user number 1 of 50 allowed.
debug1: kex_exchange_identification: banner line 2: 220-Local time is now 21:41. Server port: 21.
debug1: kex_exchange_identification: banner line 3: 220-This is a private system - No anonymous login
debug1: kex_exchange_identification: banner line 4: 220-IPv6 connections are also welcome on this server.
debug1: kex_exchange_identification: banner line 5: 220 You will be disconnected after 15 minutes of inactivity.
```

How can I use sftp in these conditions? Is there a more well suited program? Does it support something like a file .ftpignore that works like .gitignore?

## Update 1

I think I will use lftp as it is maintained and more versatile: https://lftp.yar.ru/lftp-man.html.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you're trying to use `sftp` to talk to an ordinary FTP server. That won't work as they are different protocols